# Ни сном(,) ни духом

Tags: фразеология

Есть такое выражение. "Ни сном(,) ни духом" - говорят, когда имеют в виду, что были вообще не в курсе происходящего, ничего о нем не знали (запятую ставлю в скобках, потому что не знаю точно, нужна она тут или нет).
Интересно было бы узнать происхождение этого выражения. У меня, конечно, есть свои соображения - мол, во сне приходят пророчества, плюс есть так называемые "духовидцы", но это что-то из области эзотерики уже.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы в общем-то насчет "эзотерики" не далеко от истины ушли. Но все проще.
"Духом" - это "душой". Здесь в значении - *чутьем, наитием, интуицией*. А сон - он тут, естественно, "вещий". 
Вот и получается что это два "способа" пров**и**денья (не путайте, кстати, с провид**е**нием  - в т.ч. Божественным).

Answer (score 1):

Встречал трактовку, что под "духом" подразумевается Святой Дух или посланник Небес, мол, пророки получили информацию либо через них, либо через сны в основном. Но вариант, приведённый [@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus), кажется мне куда более обоснованным.

Comment: Так одно другому не так уж и противоречит. То самое "наитие" обычно объясняли как раз воздействием святого Духа. Но тогда и писать его надо было бы с заглавной.

Comment: Большое спасибо вам за ответы! Но как насчет запятой? Нужна она тут? А то ведь это как бы устойчивый оборот речи.

Comment: Вот насчет запятой - спорно. Мне кажется, что все-таки нужна. Понимаете, обычно подобные случаи, которые запятой не требуют, трактуют не просто как устойчивое выражение с повторяющимся союзом, но как явное противопоставление: "ни день ни ночь", "ни рыба ни мясо" и проч. А у нас такого противопоставления в явной форме нет. Но такой трактовки придерживаются не все авторы. Так что тут - по наитию.